# Lampp apache does not restart

Tags: apache2

After setting up my virtual host, I restarted my lampp server with

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp
```

and I noticed Apache was not restarting.

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp  restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.3-0...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

and my virtual host domain is not working.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad I forgot to remove `dummy virtual hosts` from `httpd-vhosts.config`, which was throwing the error because `DocumentRoot` is not a directory in dummy virtual hosts.

I noticed the error in `manager-linux-x64.run's console tab`.

It's restarting and my virtual hosts running fine.